# Subscriber node

Tags: ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the ROS tutorial, they give an example of publisher and subscriber nodes.

---

```
  34 void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
  35 {
  36   ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
  37 }
```

---

I am trying to write a subscriber node for transform_broadcaster, so it will have to receive tfMessages instead of Strings. I will obviously change the body, but I am unsure of how to replace the parameter to accept tfMessages. How should I replace it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10531/subscriber-node/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of a std_msgs::String you would put a tf::tfMessage.

Warning: This is OK, for playing around and testing (maybe a laser or similar might be more suited), but you should not use that for actual working with tf. The tf library features dedicated classes encapsulating tf messages for broadcasting and subscribing (TransformListener).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2